# Custom loss function in keras- problem with implementation using K.minimum

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement a custom loss function in keras for a problem of "Partial label learning".
In my training set- each training instance is assigned a set of two candidate labels, only one
of which is correct. 
For that purpose, I want to use loss function that during training- will calculate the loss for each label, and choose the loss with minimum value.
Simplified version of this function will be something like this:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
num_labels = tf.reduce_sum(y_true) # [0,1,0,0,1]
if num_labels > 1: #create 2 seperate vectors
    y_true_1 = ?  # [0,1,0,0,0]
    y_true_2 = ?  # [0,0,0,0,1]
    loss_1 =  K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_1, y_pred)
    loss_2 =  K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_2, y_pred)
    loss = minimum(loss_1, loss_2)
else:
    loss = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

return loss
```

I tried to do it like so:

```
y_true = tf.constant([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
y_pred = tf.constant([.9, .05, .05, .5, .89, .6, .05, .01, .94])

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

def train_loss():

    y_train_copy = tf.Variable(0, dtype=y_true.dtype)
    y_train_copy = tf.assign(y_train_copy, y_true, validate_shape=False)

    label_cls = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true,1))
    raplace = tf.Variable([0.]) #Variable
    y_true_1 = tf.compat.v1.scatter_nd_update(y_train_copy, [label_cls[0]], raplace)  # [0,1,0,0,0]
    y_true_2 = tf.compat.v1.scatter_nd_update(y_train_copy, [label_cls[1]], raplace)  # [0,0,0,0,1]
    loss_1 =  K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_1, y_pred)
    loss_2 =  K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_2, y_pred)
    min_loss = tf.minimum(loss_1, loss_2)           

    return min_loss      

num_labels = tf.reduce_sum(y_true) # [0,1,0,0,1]
loss = tf.cond(num_labels > 1, 
               lambda: train_loss(), 
               lambda: K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)) #

return loss

loss = custom_loss(y_true, y_pred)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(loss))
```

The problem is that for some reason, no matter how I try to get the minimum out of the two losses, I get 0.0, even when loss_1  and loss_2 is definitely not 0

Any idea why? or a better idea for the implementation of this function?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create `y_train_copy` variable. I simplify your code and the output is the min(loss_1, loss_2).

```py
y_true = tf.constant([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
y_pred = tf.constant([.9, .05, .05, .5, .89, .6, .05, .01, .94])

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    def train_loss():
        label_cls = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1.))
        y_true_1 = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(label_cls[0], tf.size(y_true)), axis=0)
        y_true_2 = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(label_cls[1], tf.size(y_true)), axis=0)
        loss_1 =  K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_1, y_pred)
        loss_2 =  K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_2, y_pred)
        min_loss = tf.minimum(loss_1, loss_2)           
        return min_loss      

    num_labels = tf.reduce_sum(y_true) 
    loss = tf.cond(num_labels > 1, 
                   lambda: train_loss(), 
                   lambda: K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)) #

    return loss

loss = custom_loss(y_true, y_pred)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(loss))
```

### Updates:

The bug of your code is using `tf.scatter_nd_update()`, it will change the value of `y_train_copy` inplace. If you run `min_loss`, it will execute `y_true_1` and `y_true_2` together. The `y_true_2` will be always zeors. Then your `min_loss` is always zero. If you run `loss_2` alone, you can see the `loss_2` is not zero, because you didn't execute `y_true_1`.

A better choice would be `tf.scatter_nd`. You can do like this,

```py
y_true = tf.constant([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
y_pred = tf.constant([.9, .05, .05, .5, .89, .6, .05, .01, .94])

label_cls = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1.))
idx1, idx2 = tf.split(label_cls,2)

raplace = tf.constant([1.])
y_true_1 = tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(idx1, dtype=tf.int32), raplace, [tf.size(y_true)]) 
y_true_2 = tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(idx2, dtype=tf.int32), raplace, [tf.size(y_true)])  


loss_1 =  K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_1, y_pred)
loss_2 =  K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_2, y_pred)
min_loss = tf.minimum(loss_1, loss_2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(min_loss))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working! :) I spent 2 days trying to figure it out!
Also, the only reason I created the `y_train_copy` is that it kept giving me this error- `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read'`, and I saw somewhere that it might help (and it did from some reason).

Comment: Ok, so it's working fine outside the net, but when I'm trying to use it as the loss function in the model, it gives me this error:
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Outer dimensions of indices and update must match. Indices shape: [24,2], updates shape:[1]
  [[{{node loss/dense_2_loss/cond/ScatterNd}}]]
  [[loss/mul/_3467]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Outer dimensions of indices and update must match. Indices shape: [24,2], updates shape:[1]
  [[{{node loss/dense_2_loss/cond/ScatterNd}}]]`
Any idea why?

Comment: The shapes of `indices` and `updates` are not matched in `tf.scatter_nd()` method.

Comment: Yes, the problem in training is that I train with batches, so y tensors are 2D and not 1D. In this case, `idx1, idx2` (the indices)  are not right, nor do the shape of  `replace ` (the updates). 
I tried to fix it, but no success... :(
Any chance know how to adjust this code to 2D y tensors?

Comment: Please see my new post that maybe explains it better: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248695/how-can-i-use-tensorflows-scatter-nd-on-the-second-dimension-of-a-2d-tensor)