# How can I use Tensorflows scatter_nd on the second dimension of a 2D tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

**TL;DR:** How can I split 2D binary tensor of 2 labels per instance, into 2 tensors with only 1 label per instance, like in this pic:

[image]

As part of a custom loss function, I'm trying to split a multi-label y tensor, with 2 labels per instance, to 2 y tensors with 1 label per instance.
When I'm doing it on 1D y tensor, this code works great:

```
y_true = tf.constant([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
label_cls = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1.))
idx1, idx2 = tf.split(label_cls,2)
raplace = tf.constant([1.])
y_true_1 = tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(idx1, dtype=tf.int32), raplace, [tf.size(y_true)]) 
y_true_2 = tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(idx2, dtype=tf.int32), raplace, [tf.size(y_true)])  

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([y_true_1,y_true_2]))
```

And I get:

```
[array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

But when I use batches in training, I get this error:

```
Invalid argument: Outer dimensions of indices and update must match.
```

Since my "y tensors" are 2D and not 1D, and in this case- `idx1, idx2` (the indices) are not right, nor do the shape of `replace` (the updates).
For what I understand, `tf.scatter_nd` can only update the first dimension of the variable, so how can I get around it? and how can I get the needed indices for that?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're taking a convoluted path. Here's my solution. Feel it's more straightforward than the one you're trying to go with (Attempted with tf 1.14).

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.constant([[1, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 1, 0]])
_, label_inds = tf.math.top_k(y_true, k=2)
idx1, idx2 = tf.split(label_inds,2, axis=1)

y_true_1 = tf.one_hot(idx1, depth=4)
y_true_2 = tf.one_hot(idx2, depth=4)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    print(sess.run([y_true_1, y_true_2]))
```

So the idea is that you get the indices of top 2 labels for each row. Then split that into 2 columns using `tf.split`. And then use `one_hot` to convert those indices back to onehot vectors.